# How to calculate the 25th term of recursive Fibonacci Sequence in MASM(16-bit)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, fibonacci

I am programming a recursive Fibonacci Sequence through assembly language (x86) in MASM(16-bit). Here is the code:

```
DATAS SEGMENT
   TH DW 1; 
   TIP DB 0DH,0AH, 'Please Input The Num Of Fibonacci Sequence Required:$'
   NUM DW 0;
   BUF DB 0;
   TIP1 DB 0DH,0AH,'The $'
   TIP2 DB 'th Of Fibonacci Sequence is:    $'
   FORMAT DB '              $'
   FORMAT2 DB '                   $'
   ENDSTRING DB 'Do You Want To Continue The Process? Y/N $'
DATAS ENDS

STACKS SEGMENT
   STACK DW 4096 DUP(?);
STACKS ENDS

CODES SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODES,DS:DATAS,SS:STACKS

START:

MAIN PROC FAR   
  MOV AX,DATAS
  MOV DS,AX

BEG:
  MOV AX,3
  INT 0AH

  MOV AH,09H
  LEA DX,TIP
  INT 21H

  MOV AH,01H;
  INT 21H

  ;convert input to number
  SUB AL,30H
  PUSH CX
  MOV CL,10
  MUL CL
  MOV BUF,AL
  POP CX

  MOV AH,01H
  INT 21H
  SUB AL,30H
  ADD AL,BUF
  MOV AH,0
  MOV NUM,AX

  XOR AX,AX  
  PUSH DS  
  PUSH AX  
  MOV SP,STACK
  MOV AX,1 
FIB:
  PUSH AX;
  CALL Fibonacci ;

  ;disply
  push ax
  push bx
  push dx
  mov ah,09h
  lea dx,format2 
  int 21h
  mov ah,09h
  lea dx,tip1
  int 21h

  mov bx,th
  call smallbinidec

  mov ah,09h
  lea dx,tip2
  int 21h 
  pop dx
  pop bx
  pop ax

  mov bx,ax   ;disp
  call binidec
  call crlf  
  inc th
  mov ax,th
  cmp ax,num
  jbe fib

  call crlf
  jmp exit

main endp  

Fibonacci proc near  
  PUSH BP  
  MOV BP,SP  
  ADD SP,-4   
  ;ax----the value of fibonacci，cx----the number of fibonacci 
  MOV CX,[BP+4]  
  CMP CX,2  
  JA CALCULATE  ;if CX > 2 :recursive else :1
  MOV AX,1  
  ADD SP,4 
  POP BP  
  RET 2  

calculate:;sp = bp - 4 
  mov word ptr[bp-4],cx  
  dec cx  
  push cx  
  call Fibonacci   
  mov word ptr[bp-2],ax  ;save f（x-1）
  dec cx  
  push cx  ;
  call Fibonacci  
  add AX,word ptr[bp-2]   ;f（x）= f（x-1）+ f（x-2）
                          ;ax = f（x-2），word ptr[bp-2] = f（x-1）
  mov cx,word ptr[bp-4]  
  add sp,4 
  pop bp  
  ret 2  
Fibonacci endp  

binidec  proc  near 
         mov   cx, 10000d
         call  dec_div
         mov   cx, 1000d
         call  dec_div
         mov   cx, 100d
         call  dec_div
         mov   cx, 10d
         call  dec_div
         mov   cx, 1d
         call  dec_div
         ret

binidec  endp

smallbinidec  proc  near 
         mov   cx, 10d
         call  dec_div
         mov   cx, 1d
         call  dec_div
         ret

smallbinidec  endp

dec_div  proc  near
         mov   ax, bx
         mov   dx, 0
         div   cx
         mov   bx, dx
         mov   dl, al
         add   dl, 30h
         mov   ah, 2
         int   21h
         ret
dec_div  endp

CRLF PROC NEAR
         MOV AH,02H
         MOV DL,0DH
         INT 21H
         MOV AH,02H
         MOV DL,0AH
         INT 21H
         RET
CRLF ENDP

exit:
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

CODES ENDS
    END START
```

It does work well when calculating terms with n < 25. However, it went wrong when calculating the 25th term of Fibonacci Sequence.

After analyzing, I think the problem is that registers like `AX` is just 16-bit, which makes it cannot store a number larger than 65535 (less than the 25th term of Fibonacci Sequence).

A simple method is using `EAX` in MASM(32bit) instead of `AX`. Unfortunately, this is not allowed.

Therefore, how to enable this code to process terms with n >=25?

Thanks after all :)

Comment: In the old days there were no 32-bit registers: we would use two 16-bit registers (or the same one twice). You `ADD` the low parts, then `ADC` the high parts. The carry flag survives the `MOV` instruction (all the flags do), allowing you to store the result of the low sum, and load the high part.